# Alternative function for recode() that applies for "Date" class objects

Tags: r, date, group-by, dplyr, recode

```
 track        type    shortcut player  system_played date       time_period  time record_duration
   <chr>        <chr>   <chr>    <chr>   <chr>         <date>     <chr>       <dbl>           <dbl>
 1 Luigi Racew~ Three ~ No       Salam   NTSC          1997-02-15 2M 12.99S   133.                1
 2 Luigi Racew~ Three ~ No       Dan     PAL           2020-11-06 1M 57.77S   118.              112
 3 Moo Moo Farm Three ~ No       Gregg G NTSC          1997-03-07 1M 35.48S    95.5              81
 4 Moo Moo Farm Three ~ No       MR      PAL           2020-02-18 1M 25.93S    85.9             374
 5 Koopa Troop~ Three ~ No       Launsp~ NTSC          1997-05-27 1M 42.01S   102.               95
 6 Koopa Troop~ Three ~ No       Dan     PAL           2020-07-13 1M 35.29S    95.3               0
```

I have a dataset as above, and now I want to replace the column "date" with a new column "newdate" that contains the SAME values but under DIFFERENT names. For each "track", the earliest "date" will become "First", and the latest date will become "Last".
I tried this code:

```
mydata <- data %>%
  group_by(track) %>%
  mutate(newdate = recode(date, "First", .default = "Last"))
```

And encountered an error message:

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `newdate`. x no applicable method
> for 'recode' applied to an object of class "Date" i Input `newdate` is
> `recode(date, "First", .default = "Last")`. i The error occurred in
> group 1: track = "Banshee Boardwalk".

Is there an alternative function for recode() that could apply for "Date" class values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we want to change the `min` and `max` date to `character` elements, we need to first convert the `date` from `Date` class to `character`

```
library(dplyr)
mydata <- data %>%
       group_by(track) %>%
       mutate(newdate = case_when(date == min(date) ~ "First",
                       date == max(date) ~ "Last", TRUE ~ as.character(date)))
```